# Compiling dict of users in Python for search results

Tags: python, sql, json

I am not very familiar with Python or SQL and have been tasked with creating a search results page to display user information from an SQL database. I am using flask, sending JSON objects from the python back-end to the javascript/jquery front-end. I have managed to display a user when there is only one user returned from a search (a search by email address) with the following code:

```
 user = db.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?', (emailInput,)
        ).fetchone()
        if user is None:
            user_details = {
                'first' : 'error'
            }
            y = json.dumps(user_details)
            return jsonify(y)
        if user['first'] is None:
            first = ""
        else:
            first = user['first']
        if user['email'] is None:
            email = ""
        else:
            email = user['email']
        if user['last'] is None:
            last = ""
        else:
            last = user['last']
        if user['address_line1'] is None:
            address_line1 = ""
        else:
            address_line1 = user['address_line1']
        if user['address_line2'] is None:
            address_line2 = ""
        else:
            address_line2 = user['address_line2']
        if user['username'] is None:
            username = ""
        else:
            username = user['username']
        user_details = {
            'first': first,
            'last': last,
            'email': email,
            'address1': address_line1,
            'address2': address_line2,
            'username': username
        }
        y = json.dumps(user_details)
        return jsonify(y)
```

Now I want to upgrade this code with a fetchall() to return the user_details of *every* user fetched by the SQL call but I don't know how to go about it. Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT:
what I really need help with is turning multiple structs like these:

```
    user_details = {
        'first': first,
        'last': last,
        'email': email,
        'address1': address_line1,
        'address2': address_line2,
        'username': username
    }
```

into one big struct like this:

```
        users = {
            user_details1 = {
                'first': first,
                'last': last,
                'email': email,
                'address1': address_line1,
                'address2': address_line2,
                'username': username
            }
            user_details2 = {
                'first': first,
                'last': last,
                'email': email,
                'address1': address_line1,
                'address2': address_line2,
                'username': username
            }
            etc.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetchall` returns a list of lists, so you just need to iterate over the outer list (rows of the table).  For example:

```
users = db.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?', (emailInput,)
        ).fetchall()
for user in users:
        if user['first'] is None:
            <etc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spending a few hours solving this specific SQL problem, spend a few hours learning [an ORM like sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org) so you never have to write SQL again :)